# Add directory to pythonpath via command line

Tags: python

I am trying to make a bat file which add its folder to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

```
set PYTHONPATH = %PYTHONPATH%; %~dp0
```

I have a PYTHONPATH variable in my system environment variables, but this won't change anything and doesn't add any folder to the variable.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you then run python from the same `.bat` file?  If you don't, then environment changes will be lost when the .bat file ends.

Comment: Do you mean by using "python" cmd at the end like this?

Comment: set PYTHONPATH = %PYTHONPATH%; %~dp0
python

Comment: I need it to be not temporary but definitive

Comment: Then you have to alter the registry, easier to use the Windows GUI.

Comment: Thank you very much darke, I thought it was possible to change it via cmd.

Comment: Use the [SETX](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) command to permenantly set environment variables.

Comment: also from cmd this is incorrect there shouldn't be spaces: `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%~dp0`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, the correct code is:

SetX PYTHONPATH %PYTHONPATH%;%~dp0
python

Comment: if you're going to call python afterwards, you can just use `set` in the same script. note that `setx` doesn't take effect in the same window.